# Bash Script Conflict

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a bash script that creates folders and installs a software. Super user privileges are required to install the software, but it is not possible to create folders as a super user.

Here is an example of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash/
cd ~
mkdir Documents
pacman -S firefox
```

Does anyone have a clue how to overcome this conflict?

Comment: You can definitely make folders as root, but if you want only parts of your script to be run as root, just put `sudo` in front of those commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running your entire script as root, you could use [**`sudo`**](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) in your script to run only the `pacman` command as root:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir ~/Documents
sudo pacman -S firefox
```

This way the `Documents/` folder will be created in your user's home directory and then you will be prompted for the root password in order to execute the `pacman` command as super user.

---

#### Note:

As @jeremysprofile stated in the comments:

> You can definitely make folders as root

I suppose the problem is that you expect the `Documents/` folder to be created inside your user's home directory. However, if you run you script as root, `~` expands to the super user's home directory: `/root/`. So this is where you will your `Documents/` folder created with your current script.

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you very much.